# Dynamic Templates in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assume data like

```
var data = {
  name: {type: 'text', label: 'Name'},
  age:  {type: 'select', label: 'Your age', 
         options: ['< 18', '18 - 63', '> 63']},
  country: {type: 'select', label: 'Where are you from',
            options: {de: 'Germany', 'it': 'Italy'}}
}
```

and many more types.

How do I render this using AngularsJS? `ng-switch` would be possible but I dont want to "hardcode" all cases. I'm looking for some kind of dynamic directive.

```
<form>
   <div ng-repeat="element in elements">
       <label>{{element.label}}</label>
       <form-element data="element" />
   </div>
</form>
```

Result:

```
<form>
   <div>
       <label>Your name</label>
       <input name="name" type="text" />
   </div>
   <div>
       <label>Your age</label>
       <select name="age">
           <option>&lt;18</option>
           <option>18-63</option>
           <option>&gt;63</option>
       </select>
   </div>
   <div>
       <label>Where are your from</label>
       <select name="country">
           <option value="de">Germany</option>
           <option value="it">Italy</option>
       </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

Using a function as `templatePath` does not help because it has no access to the scope.

Comment: you probably are looking for angular-formly.  http://angular-formly.com/#/

Comment: The from-example is just a simple usecase of dynamic templates. But thanks, I will have a look how they did it.